# Angular uiRouter and ScrollIt

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular web app that uses uiRouter. The application is divided into a mainview that has a number of sections (about, clients, features, contact, etc) and then several forms (after user logs in) that loads these forms in their own route (register, user panel, etc).

On the main view, I use ScrollIt to scroll up and down the specific sections.

The problem I'm having is that when I navigate to, say, the register page and then I click on contact (or any other link for the main view), ScrollIt does not scroll to that section - understandably so.

The sections that it is suppose to scroll to aren't in the DOM.

Please see how ScrollIt works:
http://www.bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/

It's turned on by:

```
$.scrollIt({
    scrollTime: 1400,
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    topOffset: -20,
});
```

And by setting certain attributes in the nav and content sections:

```
<ul class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <li><a data-scroll-nav="0" title="">Get Started</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll-nav="1" title="">Features</a></li>
</ul>

...

<section data-scroll-index="0">
    ...
</section>

<section data-scroll-index="1">
    ....
</section>
```

How do I switch to the mainview via UI router and then, upon page load, trigger ScrollIt to navigate to that section?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a directive that checks if the user is on the scroll it page... If not, route to that page and listen to the $viewContentLoaded event. I added this directive on each nav item used by ScrollIt. The code then waits a few milliseconds and then triggers the click event on the element... If anyone has suggestions on how to improve this, that would e great.

Directive Code in case anyone runs into this problem.

```
function link(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.bind('click', function(e) {
        if ($state.current.name !== 'home') {
            // If not on the Scroll it view...
            e.stopPropagation();

            // Switch to the Scroll it view...
            $rootScope.go('home');

            // Listen to the view content loaded event...
            var contentLoadEvent = $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
                // Remove the event listener....
                contentLoadEvent();

                // Wait 500 MS and trigger the click event on the same nav item...
                $timeout(function() {
                    el.trigger('click');
                }, 500);
            });
        }
    })
}
```